# How to set dictionary value to ckeditor text in html file in Python flask

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, ckeditor

In my html file I have ckeditor like this:

```
{{ ckeditor.load() }}
{{ ckeditor.config(name="test_result")}}
```

I can write the content of ckeditor to database, but I cannot display existing text in the database to the ckeditor. What I need is to display dictionary value or string to ckeditor, please anyone help.

I am new to python, I tried several options I found on the net but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided your models and other related code so I'm providing a sample code you can update accordingly.

**Flask-Ckeditor** have template function named as [`ckeditor.create()`](https://flask-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html#create-a-ckeditor-textarea).
You can use `value` argument to pass default value in ckeditor. So if you want to show db value in ckeditor then do like this

```html
<form method="post">
    {% with default_text = youdb_text  %}
      {{ ckeditor.create(value=default_text) }}
    {% endwith %}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```